# Making a Sharepoint publishing site XHTML compliant

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, xhtml-transitional

I have a publishing site and I am trying to make it XHTML-transitional compliant.  I have solved most of the problem except this one.

```
     <div style='display:none' id='hidZone'><menu class="ms-SrvMenuUI">
    <ie:menuitem id="MSOMenu_Help" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/HelpIcon.gif" onmenuclick="MSOWebPartPage_SetNewWindowLocation(MenuWebPart.getAttribute(&#39;helpLink&#39;), MenuWebPart.getAttribute(&#39;helpMode&#39;))" text="Aide" type="option" style="display:none">

    </ie:menuitem>
</menu></div>
```

I have to remove the < menu > tag and his content since they do not pass the w3c validator test.

This seems to be lately injected server-side.  I have tried to remove it via javascript with no success.

Anyone could help me with this?

**Update**

I found a way to remove it by overriding the render method of the masterpage and editing the content before the render.  I am still trying to figure a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

All those tags are generated by the Ribbon Menus. If you try to validate your site with an anonymous user (if that's the case) or with a read only account and you have your ribbon in to a SPSecurityTrimmedControl the validation tool (such as HTMLValidator add on for FireFox or Total validator) will never see those tags.